# How can i get the recomendation details from LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin-api

In my application, i have to show the recomendation received by the user.. but using Linkedin API plugin, am able to get only these fileds (ID, RecommendationType, Recommeders).. what should i do to get the "Recommendation Text" for the user.

kindly help me out to solve this issue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly i got the solution.. by passing the following api url can get full recommendation details.. "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/recommendations-received"